# Getting scipy's solve_ivp function to execute intermediate task

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numeric

I am solving a fluid-structure interaction problem and I need to modify solve_ivp in order to execute a intermediate task after each time step. The algorithm should be something like this:

```
for t in time:
    for i in maxiter:
        1 - Solve one time step of the fluid nonlinear equation keeping the solid fixed (RK45). 
        2 - Solve a nonlinear equation for the solid (Radau or user defined). 
        3 - Update the fluid geometry
        if converge: 
            break
```

The challenge is how to couple two instances of the integrator. With solve_ivp I cannot control the time step as I wish, the algorithm chooses the time step to favor stability. I could accept this, since the time scale of the fluid is much faster than the time scale of the solid; so the time step in 1 would fix the time in 2. The two options I see are:

Option 1:

1. Instantiate the fluid integrator object and run it for a small fixed delta T (the integrator will do sub-steps, probably not many).
2. Store fluid force information.
3. Instantiate a solid integrator object with the same delta T and solve using the previously calculated fluid forces.
4. Check convergence and go back to 1).

Option 2):

1. Instantiate a fluid integrator object setting the final time to the TOTAL time of the simulation.
2. After each (automatic) integration step, call a user defined solid integrator FROM INSIDE the solve_ivp function (needs modification of solve_ivp.
3. Check convergence inside solve_ivp and, if False, execute a new integration with the same time step but with geometry updated (not easy probably).

The drawback of option 1 is that I need to instantiate and the discard a large number of integrator objects (probably more than 10 million). While the drawback of Option 2) is that I need to modify solve_ivp to: a)execute intermediate task (the function itself does not allow the execution of  intermediate task, only allows storing event information) and b) re-integrate with the same delta T if convergence is False (is possible?).

I wonder if anyone sees a better approach for this integration loop? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For such a scenario, it is probably best to directly use the solver you require, for example [RK45](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html), rather than `solve_ivp`. Each solver has a `step` method you can use to advance the integration by exactly one step.

Comment: Thanks @Patol75 ! I didnt know about the step method in the solver classes. Thank you very much !